# Java - Selenium - Inconsistent behavior when using Assert

Tags: java, selenium

I am experiencing some weird, inconsistent behavior when trying to assert that an error message is displayed.

I have 2 tests, both of them are doing the same thing, except from sending different values into the form and checking for a different error message.

```
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\dan.febry\\Desktop\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        driver.get("https://mywebsite.com");

        driver.findElement(By.id("Identifier")).sendKeys("username");
        driver.findElement(By.id("Password")).sendKeys("password");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/form/button")).click();

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[4]/div/button")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[4]/div/div/form[1]/button")).click();

        driver.findElement(By.id("OldPassword")).sendKeys("Password!23");
        driver.findElement(By.id("NewPassword")).sendKeys("Password123!");
        driver.findElement(By.id("ConfirmPassword")).sendKeys("");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"form0\"]/div[5]/div/button")).click();

        List<WebElement> allElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"form0\"]/div[4]/ul/li"));
        Assert.assertEquals(allElements.size(), 1);
        Assert.assertEquals(allElements.get(0).getText(), "The new password and confirmation password do not match.");

        // TODO Verify failed counter has not gone up.

        driver.close();

    }

    @Test
    public void ChangePasswordCurrentPasswordIncorrect() {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\dan.febry\\Desktop\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        driver.get("https://mywebsite.com");

        driver.findElement(By.id("Identifier")).sendKeys("username");
        driver.findElement(By.id("Password")).sendKeys("password");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/form/button")).click();

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[4]/div/button")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[4]/div/div/form[1]/button")).click();

        driver.findElement(By.id("OldPassword")).sendKeys("Password@123");
        driver.findElement(By.id("NewPassword")).sendKeys("Password123!");
        driver.findElement(By.id("ConfirmPassword")).sendKeys("Password123!");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"form0\"]/div[5]/div/button")).click();

        List<WebElement> allElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"form0\"]/div[4]/ul/li"));
        Assert.assertEquals(allElements.size(), 1);
        Assert.assertEquals(allElements.get(0).getText(), "Incorrect password.");

        // TODO Verify failed counter has gone up.
        // TODO Reset failed counter value

        driver.close();

    }`
```

The first test runs, passes and asserts the text correctly. However, the second test fails and shows the following error:

java.lang.AssertionError: expected [Incorrect password.] but found []

The HTML is:

```html
<div class="validation-summary-errors text-danger" data-valmsg-summary="true">
  <ul>
    <li>Incorrect password.</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="text-danger validation-summary-errors" data-valmsg-summary="true">
  <ul>
    <li>The new password and confirmation password do not match.</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

PS. Not sure if I have missed out some important information here, so let me know if I should give some more info in relation to this issue.

Comment: Are you sure the locator is correct in the second case? I would change it to a CSS selector like, `#form0 div.text-danger li` which seems to fit both cases.

Comment: Thanks Jeff. Yes, it was the xpath I was using that was causing the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible not getting the correct `Xpath` hence it returning Zero list.

Instead of this xpath

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"form0\"]/div[4]/ul/li"))
```

Try below `Xpath` and give some time `WebDriverWait` to find the elements

```
 WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
 wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@class='validation-summary-errors text-danger']/ul/li")))
```

Comment: Thanks Kajal! It was the xpath that was causing the problem. I added the WebDriverWait and changed the xpath and it worked. If I then keep the WebDriverWait in the code but keep my old xpath, it times out when trying to find the element.

Comment: @dannyfebry : Glad to help you.